# Sending an Email in VBA for Excel based on dropdown box text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to send an email to a staff member when they have been selected for allocation.
I select them from a dropdown box in the spreadsheet, this then opens an Outlook mailitem and has their email address already entered, "subject" and "body" / If possible, if the row of the cell of the staff member is selected, G2 for L2, B2, C2, E2, I2 to be in the body of the text.

For G3 it is L3, B3, C3, E3, I3
For G4 it is L4, B4 etc.

```vb
Sub EmailRemittance2()

Dim eRecipient As String
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objEmail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

eSubject = ActiveSheet.Range("W14").Value
eRecipient = ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value
eBody = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value

With objEmail
    .Display
    .To = eRecipient
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = eSubject
    .Body = "See below for details, Link is to Young person's SharePoint Folder, Thank you" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value & vbNewLine & "Deadline:" & ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best Wishes" & .Body
    '.Send
End With
End Sub
```

I now need all row 2s to be 3s and so on, but it would be better to have it just do the row the button is on and have that included in the macro instead of 300 macros.

Updated Macro

```
Sub Cycle_Emails_By_Row()
    
    Dim I As Long           'Iteration
    Dim eListing As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long     'Last Used Row
    
    Set eListing = Worksheets("2022")
    LastRow = eListing.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No emails addresses found.", vbOKOnly, "Error:"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With eListing
        For I = 2 To LastRow
            Application.StatusBar = "Sending email # " & I - 1 & " of " & LastRow - 1
            Call SendEmail( _
                .Range("K" & I).Value, _
                .Range("C" & I).Value, _
                .Range("D" & I).Value, _
                .Range("E" & I).Value) _
                .Range("F" & I).Value) _
                .Range("I" & I).Value)
        Next I
    End With
    
    Application.StatusBar = "All emails sent."
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.StatusBar = False



Sub SendEmail(eRecipient As String, eSubject As String, eBody As String, Optional eAttachmentDir As String)

Dim eRecipient As String
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objEmail As Object


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)


eSubject = ActiveSheet.Range("W14").Value
eRecipient = ActiveSheet.Range("K").Value
eBody = Body = "See below for details, Link is to Young person's SharePoint Folder, Thank you" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("C").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("D").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("E").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("F").Value & vbNewLine & "Deadline:" & ActiveSheet.Range("I").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best Wishes"

With objEmail
    .Display
    .To = eRecipient
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = eSubject
    .Body = eBody
    '.Send
End With


End Sub
```

The Form control box is in "L" and when pressed adds a 1 in that cell, which is perfect, Is there not a way to reference this? so when If "L" equals 1 eRecipent = Last row - 1? as "K" is where the email is.

**Update**

Again thanks for your patience and help. Ahh I did not notice 1 and 2.

for 3. So for data protection reasons I can't show, but i'll explain

"K" - is the column with the email, the row is based on where I click the form control button. I want the eRecipient to be this

Ebody = below
"C" - Name
"D" - DOB
"E" - Place
"F" - Case folder
"I" - Deadline

these again on the same row as the the form control button i clicked to use that macro.

So the original code works perfect with just putting the exact cell reference but then I would have to make 300 macros.

Can it reference the cell the form button is in?

And thank you

Comment: i think 1. just look on here for a code that sends an email from excel this is fairly standard and there should also be tutorials online.  then 2. you need to make that drop down, that really depends on how you want it to work, honestly i'd problem just put a drop down in A1 and then a button in B1 that activates the code.  See how you get on and ask questions if you're having trouble along the way.  (it is all possible though, as described)

Comment: Okay, C, D, E, F, I, but where is your eRecipient? does it need to be indexed by the name?

Comment: I believe so, In "K" eRecipient = Column "K" and the row that the button is on, as the emails can be change and follow the table list from the start. If this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Data Validation to make a drop down list. Data > Data Validation > Data Validation... > List > select range (ideally named range or table)

[image]

2. Add whatever other field you may want like email address, body, subject... Here, I'm having the address be pre-populated by my employee info table (same table used for data validation) I'm also putting a formula in cell A6 to auto-form-fill a simple message.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub EmailRemittance()

Dim eSubject As String
Dim eRecipient As String
Dim eBody As String
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objEmail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

eSubject = ActiveSheet.Range("A21").Value
eRecipient = ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Value
eBody = ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Value

With objEmail
    .To = eRecipient
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = eSubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
    .Body = eBody
    .Display
    '.Send
End With
End Sub
```

3. See above ^^^ Use this simple code that can be found in some form on a myriad of websites to build your email. Please note you MUST reference "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object library" for this to work.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and through this, I have been able to understand more, rather than just taking your code and going. It's really helped in how I understand VBA and I have been customizing and editing it to suit my needs. Thanks to your help I've managed to make a excellent system.

Comment: Hi, So as said works perfect, how do a duplicate the code to work for each row, my code is not exact same, I have modified to work perfect for a row, but don't wish to duplicate the macro 300 times, i just need it to do it for the row the button is on? will update post to have my new code, Thank you

Comment: You could Either run a `For i = x to y ... (place the whole code here) ... Next i` loop inside your sub, where you reference ranges like `Range("A" & i).value`  - or - you could write a second sub that does your looping and passes variables to your email sub. The way to pass variables would be to call the sub like: `Call EmailRemittance( ebody here, erecipient here, esubject here)`. First you will need to move the variable declaration into the sub line for EmailRemittance like `Sub EmailRemittance(eBody As String, eRecipient As String, eSubject As String)`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand, apologies, thank you for the help, I'm going to try figure it out. if this helps I want when command button pressed to use the values in the same row and in column "K" "I" "A" "B"

Comment: Okay See second answer below>

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through emails.
Once working correctly, change `.display` to `.send`.
I've added optional attachment functionality.
I would recommend adding in your own error handling.
I'm keeping a copy of this as it works like a hot damn.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cycle_Emails_By_Row()
    
    Dim I As Long           'Iteration
    Dim eListing As Worksheet 'Email Listing Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long     'Last Used Row
    
    Set eListing = Worksheets("EmailListing")
    LastRow = eListing.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No emails addresses found.", vbOKOnly, "Error:"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With eListing
        For I = 2 To LastRow
            Application.StatusBar = "Sending email # " & I - 1 & " of " & LastRow - 1
            Call SendEmail( _
                .Range("A" & I).Value, _
                .Range("B" & I).Value, _
                .Range("C" & I).Value, _
                .Range("D" & I).Value)
        Next I
    End With
    
    Application.StatusBar = "All emails sent."
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(eRecipient As String, eSubject As String, eBody As String, Optional eAttachmentDir As String)
    
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Dim objAttachment As Object
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(OLMailItem)
    Set objAttachment = objEmail.Attachments
    
    If eAttachmentDir <> "" Then
        objAttachment.Add eAttachmentDir
    End If
    
    With objEmail
        .To = eRecipient
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = eSubject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
        .Body = eBody
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
    eAttachmentDir = ""

End Sub
```

[image: Example of spreadsheet]

> > > Continuation

Okay so a few things:

1. You're missing an `End Sub` on `Cycle_Emails_By_Row`
2. in your `SendEmail` Sub you have dim'ed `eRecipient` twice, keep only
   `Sub SendEmail(eRecipient As String, ...`
3. I see you've added 2 columns to:

```
        Call SendEmail( _
            .Range("K" & I).Value, _
            .Range("C" & I).Value, _
            .Range("D" & I).Value, _
            .Range("E" & I).Value) _
            .Range("F" & I).Value) _
            .Range("I" & I).Value)
```

What are there for? could you please post a picture of the data you're referencing?
Basically when you declare variables in the `Sub` statement, it means those variables accept input when sub is called. Consider the following example.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExampleSub1()
    Call ExampleSub2("This will become the Msgbox text.", "This will become the header")
End Sub
Sub ExampleSub2(sText As String, sHeader As String)
    MsgBox sText, vbOKOnly, sHeader
End Sub
```

[image: Examplemsgbox]
We call `ExampleSub1` which passes variables to `Examplesub2` which `examplesub2` then uses.
So getting back to your example, if you're going to add variables you're trying to pass to your `SendEmail` Sub, you need to add more "Ports" in your `SendEmail` Sub to accept those variables.

Comment: Does it make sense how the first sub is passing the variables to the second sub?

Comment: Thank you Cameron, I'm running into an Error. I Kind of get it, but still struggling, I'm going to update my question with the edited form of your code that fits how I feel it should be, if you understand? I really appreciate you patience, I'm Loving trying to figure it all out and troubleshooting. Thanks again

Comment: @EdHaswell I've added onto the above answer. see if that makes sense better.

Comment: Thank Cameron if you see above for update. Apologies if I'm explaining things you already understand of my problem